# My DIVs do not expand after I drag them using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a simple input button that will generate text below the button.

If I do NOT drag the DIV, it all works normally on submit - meaning the DIV expands for the added text. However, once I drag it the DIV will no longer expand. Any ideas on why this happening? My code is below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const dragDIV = $('#my-DIV');
  $(function() {
    $(dragDIV).draggable();
  });

  $('#submit-form').on('click', () => submit('#my-form'));

  function submit() {
    let text = `Testing<br>
        Testing<br>
        Testing`;

    let newDIV = document.createElement('div');
    newDIV.innerHTML = text;
    document.getElementById('my-DIV').appendChild(newDIV);
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  background-color: rgb(59, 59, 59);
  color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
}

.div {
  background-color: black;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 3px;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-DIV" class="div">
  <input type="button" id="submit-form" value="Submit">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here are two pictures..

[IMG - Result of hitting submit without dragging DIV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx4Fr.png)

[IMG - Result of then dragging the DIV - then hitting submit again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiFnM.png)

I've tried messing with display properties but nothing seems to work. I can make the default size of the DIV bigger, but I want it to expand only if needed.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the jQueryUI draggable widget sets a height after dragging stops. The easiest way to fix this is to use the draggable's stop event and change the height back to auto:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const dragDIV = $('#my-DIV');
  $(function() {
    $(dragDIV).draggable({
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css('height', 'auto')
      }
    });
  });

  $('#submit-form').on('click', () => submit('#my-form'));

  function submit() {
    let text = `Testing<br>
        Testing<br>
        Testing`;

    let newDIV = document.createElement('div');
    newDIV.innerHTML = text;
    document.getElementById('my-DIV').appendChild(newDIV);
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  background-color: rgb(59, 59, 59);
  color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
}

.div {
  background-color: black;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 3px;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-DIV" class="div">
  <input type="button" id="submit-form" value="Submit">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: As a side note, I'd move away from jQueryUI as it's very old and not maintained anymore.